# sparse matrix diagonal multiplication using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a symmetric sparse matrix M and a diagonal matrix D. I want to compute DMD

M is created as a SparseTensor, and D can be represented either as tf.diag or a SparseTensor - in theory it should be entirely possible to evaluate DMD without going through a dense matrix, but I can't figure out how - does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some tips.

Note that the effect of multiplying D before and after M is to multiply each non-zero element M(i, j) with D(i, i) and D(j, j). See [here](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c108.html).

Say P = DMD. To construct P as a [sparse tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/sparse_ops/sparse_tensor_representation#SparseTensor), you will need indices, value, and shape. You can set indices and shape as M's indices and shape, and compute value with [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/functional_ops/higher_order_operators#map_fn) over M's value and D (D could be a dense 1D Tensor).

Comment: Could you possibly add some code and updated references to this answer? The links are broken.